TypeORM inner join raw array
I have the table tasks with the columns id, user_id, title, status. I have to select all users with all their pending and finished tasks.
The interface of the expected result:
{
  user_id: string;
  pending_tasks: Array<{
    id: string;
    user_id: string;
    title: string;
    status: 'pending';
  }>;
  finished_tasks: Array<{
    id: string;
    user_id: string;
    title: string;
    status: 'finished';
  }>;
}

Is it possible with TypeORM?
P.S. There is no table users. I have only one table tasks.
